# Insert a spreadsheet in a form VB

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a spreadsheet like functionality in a form where user can copy a subset data from one spreadhseet and paste it in the spreadsheet in the form. 
I tried creating a datasheet form but I am unable to add anything to it. I also tried creating bunch of text boxes for representing columns but in this case I can only paste one row from spreadhseet to this form.

Any help or pointer will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that allows the user to [upload a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3kksch7.aspx) (spreadsheet that has been saved in a .csv format) and then use the [TextFieldParser object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx) to read the file.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for this quick response. Adding a option to allow users to upload file is not the requirement. Requirement is that user should be able to select a bunch of rows from a spreadhseet and paste it in the form and if needed edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a List box, however you will need to set the columns and the user will have to make sure they select only that amount of columns. Then have a paste button in the form which will take the clipboard and add it to the list box.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using datasheet bound to a table.
thanks for the help guys.